# What to return from a function if illegally passed in bad parameters so it's good for debugging.

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function that will performance a basic logging. For example, when a button is clicked, this function will log the button is clicked.

```
var logClicks = function (buttonName) {
  if (typeof buttonName === 'undefined' || buttonName === null) {
    return false;
  }
  // Perform log function, code omitted. 
}
```

My question is the `if` check that I have. I want to make sure the `buttonName` that gets passed in is legal, it's not `undefined` or `null`. Is this check enough?

Also not sure if `return false` is the correct way to handle this? Should I `return false` or just `return`? Or do something else instead?

It's pure front-end work.

Comment: I would recommend that you throw an error.

Comment: Why not check, if `buttonName` is not a type of string?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this check enough?

Yes.

An alternative (which some may find less readable, but others may differ) would be

```
if (buttonName == null)
```

because both `undefined` and `null` are `== null`, and nothing else is.

> Also not sure if return false is the correct way to handle this? Should I return false or just return? Or do something else instead?

That's entirely up to you and how you intend to use the function. As [Jite said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194315/what-to-return-from-a-function-if-illegally-passed-in-bad-parameters-so-its-goo/39194324#comment65729199_39194315), if the argument is invalid, throwing an error would make sense:

```
if (/*...check...*/) {
    throw new Error("'buttonName' cannot be undefined or null");
}
```